# Fix a malformed request in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4

Let's say a particular browser has a bug and sends malformed requests.  I would like to detect these browsers by their agent-type.  The problem is the browser fails to send a required header.  So the trick, I think, would be to 1. Detect the bad browser by http_user_agent and 2. add in the missing header which should fix the request and allow Apache to continue as normal, right?  So here is our http_user_agent: Allscripts-HIE-Broker/1.1.0.10 and the missing header is:

```
start-info: "text/xml"
```

Here are the headers that the browser DOES send:

```
POST /csp/hsbus/HS.IHE.XDSb.Repository.Services.cls HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>"; boundary="79a640a5-d64d-4ed9-882d-f9b652f27cf2+custom";start-info="application/soap+xml"
Host: example.com
Content-Length: 132691
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4
```

Here's what I started to write for the configuration.  I wasn't sure if this needed to be a filter or if it could be a substitution just by itself or what:

```
FilterProvider ALLSCRIPTS_FILTER SUBSTITUTE "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ m|^Allscripts-HIE-Broker|"
```

For the substitution, I thought of something like:

```
Substitute "s|\r\nContent-Length:|start-info: "text/xml"\r\nContent-Length:|i"
```

But again, not sure where to put it.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!
Note: I'm using Apache 2.4.6.

I may have figured out a solution but I'll have to wait to test it out.  Until I can, does this look like it would work?

```
Header %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ "m|^Allscripts-HIE-Broker|" merge start-info expr="text/xml"
```

Comment: Your `Header` directive looks right to me.

Comment: I think this is almost working but there is a compatibility issue because I'm using 2.4.6 (locked in, unfortunately) and expr became available in version 2.4.10.

Comment: It looks like the other issue is the Header directive for Apache 2.4.6 doesn't have a conditional feature.

Comment: Oh. Yeah, a bunch of changes were introducted in 2.4.7, and unfortunately RHEL7 and CentOS 7 standardized on 2.4.6. If you're in RHEL7, I highly recommend using the httpd24* packages from RHSCL, which are version 2.4.34.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I'm stuck with 2.4.6.  Could the http24* packages be added without doing an actual upgrade?  Maybe sounds silly but I don't officially maintain the server where all this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Header` directive is close, but not quite right. The condition argument before `merge` isn't an expression, but optionally either of the words `onsuccess` or `always`. See [Header](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header) for a (not too clear) explanation.

This should work:

```
Header merge start-info text/xml expr="%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ m|^Allscripts-HIE-Broker|"
```

If your version of Apache is to old to allow the condition, you can wrap it in an `<If>` instead:

```
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ m|^Allscripts-HIE-Broker|">
  Header merge start-info text/xml
</If>
```